# Spring boot JSP 404: Page not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I am trying to run a simple Spring Boot application. However when I run it, I get the following error:

"Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback."

Tue Nov 12 09:31:36 AST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp

Here is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>jspDemo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>jspDemo</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>


              <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>

            </dependency>
            <!-- JSTL -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- To compile JSP files -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>

            </dependency>


        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

IndexController.java

```
    package com.pack.springMVC;

    import java.util.Map;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    @Controller
    public class IndexController {

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String home(Map<String, Object> model) {
            model.put("message", "HowToDoInJava Reader !!");
            return "index";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/next")
        public String next(Map<String, Object> model) {
            model.put("message", "You are in new page !!");
            return "next";
        }

    }
```

MvcConfiguration.java

```
    package com.pack.springMVC;



    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;


    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan
    public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer
    {
        @Override
        public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
            registry.viewResolver(resolver);
        }
    }
```

JspDemoApplication.java

```
    package com.pack.springMVC;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
    import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class JspDemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(JspDemoApplication.class);
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(JspDemoApplication.class, args);
        }

    }
```

index.jsp

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
    <html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1>Spring Boot JSP Example</h1>
                <h2>Hello ${message}</h2>

                Click on this <strong><a href="next">link</a></strong> to visit another page.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

next.jsp

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
    <html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1>Another page</h1>
                <h2>Hello ${message}</h2>

                Click on this <strong><a href="/">link</a></strong> to visit previous page.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

application.properties

> spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
>   spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

Comment: what's the path of index.jsp

Comment: src/main/resource/webapp/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```